# Why are the names of the 12 apostles and 12 tribes written where they are in the New Jerusalem?

Tags: revelation, israel, apostles

> **Revelation 21:12-14** "**12** Also she had a great and high wall with twelve gates, and twelve angels at the gates, and names written
> on them, which are the names of the twelve tribes of the children of
> Israel: **13** three gates on the east, three gates on the north,
> three gates on the south, and three gates on the west.  **14** Now the
> wall of the city had twelve foundations, and on them were the names of
> the twelve apostles of the Lamb."

To clarify the question, why are the tribes written on the gates, and the apostles on the foundation, and not the other way around? What could "gate" and "foundation" signify?

I take this passage literally but would still like to try to grasp the metaphorical significance. I would appreciate an answer pointing to some reading on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bibleref](https://www.bibleref.com/Revelation/21/Revelation-21-12.html) puts in nicely:

> The New Jerusalem is secure. Nothing and no one except what is
> righteous is allowed to enter (Revelation 21:27). A massive high wall
> with twelve gates surrounds the city. Twelve angels guard the gates.
> **The gates serve not only to symbolize security, but they also serve as
> memorials. The names of the twelve tribes of Israel are inscribed on
> the gates.**
>
> Walls and gates were used in Bible times to fortify cities. Wooden or
> iron gates closed at night to keep out enemy soldiers and/or
> plunderers. Inside the cities were narrow streets and courtyards.
> Buildings stood around the courtyards. Of course, enemies were known
> to scale the walls and crash the gates. When Jerusalem fell to the
> Babylonians, the city's walls were left in ruins. It became Nehemiah's
> mission to return from captivity to lead a delegation in the
> rebuilding of Jerusalem's walls (Nehemiah 1). The wall of the New
> Jerusalem will never fall, and its gates will never be breached.
>
> This, of course, is meant as a highly symbolic gesture. In eternity,
> there won't be any wickedness or unrighteousness to be protected from.
> Nor will there be any evil, danger, or harm from which to be
> protected. The existence of these walls, and gates, serve as
> real-but-symbolic emblems proclaiming the safety and security of those
> living in New Jerusalem.

The symbolism: We know that the twelve tribes of Israel are the Old Covenant community, while the twelve apostles are the New Covenant community established by Jesus Christ. By inscribing the names of the tribes on the gates and the names of the apostles on the foundations, it signifies the connection between the Old and New Covenants, with Jesus Christ serving as the cornerstone (Ephesians 2:20) that brings them together as the one who fulfilled the law (Matthew 5:17).

---

> Foundations of ancient cities often are extensions of the rows of
> stones making up the walls, going down to the bedrock. Jerusalem’s
> first-century walls and foundation stones have been excavated. Huge
> stones, some of which are five feet wide, four feet high and 30 feet
> long, weighing more than 80 tons, go down 14 to 19 layers below ground
> level.
>
> Of more importance, however, are the names of the 12 apostles. This
> illustrates what Paul writes about when he says the church is “**built
> on the foundation of the apostles and prophets**, with Christ Jesus
> Himself as the cornerstone. The whole building, being put together by
> Him, grows into a holy sanctuary in the Lord. You also are being built
> together for God’s dwelling in the Spirit” (Eph. 2:20-22).
> [[1]](https://oncedelivered.net/2017/01/17/a-massive-high-wall-revelation-2112-14/)

**On the Foundations:** The stability and support of a structure are ensured by its foundations. By engraving the names of the twelve apostles on the foundations of the New Jerusalem, it highlights the fundamental importance of the apostles in founding and growing the Church. Selected by Jesus to bear witness to His teachings, crucifixion, and resurrection, the apostles were instrumental in sharing the Gospel worldwide. Therefore, the apostles symbolize the solid base on which the Church stands, with Jesus Christ serving as the cornerstone.

**On the Gates:** The inscriptions of the twelve tribes on the gates may represent God's commitment to His covenant promises to the patriarchs and the nation of Israel. In the Old Testament, God made various pledges to the tribes of Israel concerning their land, blessings, and safety. By showcasing their names prominently on the gates of the celestial city, it acts as a constant reminder of God's steadfast faithfulness in keeping His promises to His selected people.

Since Israel was God's chosen people and the 12 tribes are on the gates, it may mean that God's people are those who, on the very entrance of the city, their names are known.

Comment: A cornerstone is not a capstone. They are precisely opposite by definition.

Comment: No problem. We can remove these comments I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The book of Revelation is written symbolically and the image in Rev 21:12-14 is no exception.  The OP asks specifically about two of these symbols:

1. **The Names of the 12 apostles on the foundation stone of the New Jerusalem**

The entire basis of belief and practice of the NT church was the teaching of the apostles about faith in Christ, Acts 2:42, 4:2, 6:2, 15:2, 16:4, 1 Tim 2:7, etc.

2. **The names of the twelve tribes if Israel on the gates to the New Jerusalem**

This appears to be an allusion to Rev 7 where we see the saved as described in two ways:

- what John heard (V4-8): 144,000 from the 12 tribes of Israel
- what John saw (V9, 10): an uncountable multitude from every nation and tribe and people and tongue

That is, the New Jerusalem has an entrance for every person no matter their origin.  Matthew Poole expresses it thus:

> **And had twelve gates**: the use of the gates of a city, are to let persons in and out. The church is said to have twelve gates, because
> of the free liberty of access to the church while it was militant, and
> to signify that the church in heaven will be made up of persons come
> into it from all parts; or for the greater state and glory of it.

Comment: "the church in heaven" ... say what now?

Comment: @davidianwalker - Church in heaven consists of the saved saints.

Comment: I'd love to see a biblical reference.

Comment: @davidianwalker - I think that is quirk of his terminology.

Comment: Considering the large amount of "christians" that incorrectly propound believers going to heaven that "quirk" is negligent and should be corrected. Slip of the pen maybe but inexcusable once pointed out.